# Installing drivers for USB Wifi adapter from cd

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

I've just bought a Wireless-N USB Adapter (I just copied the name of the box) and it comes with a driver cd. In the cd I found 4 folders, Android, Linux, Mac and Windows. In the Linux folder I found a folder (DOC) with 3 pdf files, and three tar files: `DPA_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130916.tar.bz2`, `DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211.tar.bz2` and `RT5572_RT5372_Linux_AP_V2.7.1.1_Beta_DPA_20121113.tar.bz2`.

The problem is that the 3 pdf files (Software Programming Guide 3.3, Software Porting Guide, Software Programming Guide 1.2) are like instructions about how to programme or adapt the card, I just want to install the driver and make the card work (I have connected it but nothing happens)

What should I do?

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Lenovo G400 Laptop (the internal wireless card doesn't work), and I'm not an expert in Ubuntu/Linux systems :)

When I put `sudo lsusb`, on a terminal it shows the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:148d Syntek 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Content of the bzipped files, 
[image: here]

[image: here]

[image: here]

[image: and here]

```
~/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211$ make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux_symb.o
  CC [M]  /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_rbus_pci_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
In file included from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘duplicate_pkt’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:516:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pHeader802_3, HdrLen);
                  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:494:61: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisMoveMemory’
 #define NdisMoveMemory(Destination, Source, Length) memmove(Destination, Source
                                                             ^
In file included from ./include/linux/bitmap.h:8:0,
                 from ./include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:18,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
./include/linux/string.h:312:24: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t {aka unsigned int}’
 __FORTIFY_INLINE void *memmove(void *p, const void *q, __kernel_size_t size)
                        ^
In file included from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:518:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pData, DataSize);
                  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:494:61: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisMoveMemory’
 #define NdisMoveMemory(Destination, Source, Length) memmove(Destination, Source
                                                             ^
In file included from ./include/linux/bitmap.h:8:0,
                 from ./include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:18,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
./include/linux/string.h:312:24: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t {aka unsigned int}’
 __FORTIFY_INLINE void *memmove(void *p, const void *q, __kernel_size_t size)
                        ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘duplicate_pkt_with_VLAN’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:583:9: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘VLAN_8023_Header_Copy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         skb->tail, FromWhichBSSID,
         ^
In file included from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:37:0:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rt_os_util.h:214:7: note: expected ‘PUCHAR {aka unsigned char *}’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t {aka unsigned int}’
 UCHAR VLAN_8023_Header_Copy(
       ^
In file included from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:588:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pData, DataSize);
                  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:494:61: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisMoveMemory’
 #define NdisMoveMemory(Destination, Source, Length) memmove(Destination, Source
                                                             ^
In file included from ./include/linux/bitmap.h:8:0,
                 from ./include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:63,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:37,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:80,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from ./include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:18,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
./include/linux/string.h:312:24: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t {aka unsigned int}’
 __FORTIFY_INLINE void *memmove(void *p, const void *q, __kernel_size_t size)
                        ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘ClonePacket’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:709:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   pClonedPkt->tail = pClonedPkt->data + pClonedPkt->len;
                    ^
In file included from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsPktInit’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:967:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:728:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(pRxPkt, pData, DataSize);
  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘wlan_802_11_to_802_3_packet’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:755:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  pOSPkt->tail = pOSPkt->data + pOSPkt->len;
               ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘__RtmpOSFSInfoChange’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1209:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t {aka const struct <anonymous>}’
   pOSFSInfo->fsuid = current_fsuid();
                    ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1210:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t {aka const struct <anonymous>}’
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid();
                    ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsFreeSpinLock’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:4429:8: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  pLock = (OS_NDIS_MINIPORT_TIMER *) (pLockOrg->pContent);
        ^
In file included from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:63,
                 from /home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsPktTailAdjust’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:967:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                    ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:991:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt, GET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt), (-_removedTagLen)); \
  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:5257:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST’
  OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST(pNetPkt, removedTagLen);
  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:967:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:991:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt, GET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt), (-_removedTagLen)); \
  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:5257:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST’
  OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST(pNetPkt, removedTagLen);
  ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpThreadPidKill’:
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:526:37: error: implicit declaration of function ‘kill_pid’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define KILL_THREAD_PID(_A, _B, _C) kill_pid((_A), (_B), (_C))
                                     ^
/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:5355:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘KILL_THREAD_PID’
  return KILL_THREAD_PID(PID, SIGTERM, 1);
         ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic'
Makefile:500: recipe for target 'osutil' failed
make[1]: *** [osutil] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/brandon/DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211/UTIL'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the output of "lsusb" as well as the contents of the bzipped files? It's rare for linux to need driver files for network adapters... also have a look at the output of "dmesg" and post lines pertaining to your device... we should be able to determine the chipset that way, see if it's loading a module, and if not see why...

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I have edited the post with the information you asked. Is it useful?

Comment: It looks like the card isn't even showing up to the system, I don't see a network card in the lsusb output and the dmesg output is information on a pnp sound device (SunFounder USB 2.0 Mini Microphone)... try using a different usb port... and do the following... unplug the card and run dmesg and lsusb.... then plug the card in and run dmesg and lsusb again and see what is different... this will show us if the device is being recognized when it's plugged in. if it's not showing up at all try plugging into a different computer and see if it works. the device could be defective or mispackaged

Comment: and on the bziped files.... once we figure out what your chipset is and that the card is not defective you will extract the appropriate file and compile it... eg: cd ~/driver then run make and sudo make install...

Comment: what does the readme have to say in DPA_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130916.tar.bz2?

Comment: Oh! Forgive me. I didin't read "Sound Device" on what I posted. I've installed the driver on Windows and everything works fine.  So, the device seems to be Ok. In my laptop, after plugging, unplugging the device nothing seems to change in "lsusb" and "dmesg". I'm sure about the first one (nothing has changed) but in the second one is difficult to ensure that nothing has changed (is a lot of information)

Comment: when you plug/unplug the device it should be noted at the end of the dmesg output... only the last 10 or so lines will be relevant... you can also try "dmesg | tail" to cut down on the amount of data spit out.

Comment: Nope. Ive just spended 15 minutes reading all the "dmesg" output. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76860/discussion-between-joshua-besneatte-and-edonbrayn).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file names of the the available drivers, one can deduce that the device uses either the MT7601U or RT5572 ralink chipset.

MT7601U should just work automatically for Ubuntu 16.04 and up.

RT5572 uses the rt2800usb driver and should also just work automatically.

Looking at the error messages and warnings you are getting when you try to compile the drivers I believe they were written for older kernels and so won't compile on your system.

The fact that nothing shows up in either lsusb or dmesg or syslog when you plug/unplug the adapter makes me think that your USB slots are not providing enough power for the device. Try using a powered USB hub.

Comment: It shows an error when I run "make" on the folder, I've edited the question with the output (it shows only the DPA_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.4_20121211.tar.bz2, but the error output with both)

Comment: I apologize for not puting in "code format" the output but I can't did it with so large info